# How can I complete this task more easily? [Java]

Tags: java

This is for a game I'm making. When the hero walks on the tile that makes up Row 1, Tile 1 of the Earth Mountain, it changes all the adjacent tiles into a different type of terrain.

pos is the player's position.

Level.set is needed to change the tiles.

Gamescene.update is needed to display the tiles.

Dungeon.observe is needed to stop the change.

enter is when the player enters the tile to change the tile appearance.

leave is for when the player leaves the tile, and changes the tile appearance back.

All the real work happens in the code below.

Here's what I've got:

```
public static void enter( int pos ) {
    switch(Dungeon.level.map[pos]){
        case Terrain.MT_EARTH_R1T1:
            Level.set(pos, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R1T1);
            Level.set(pos+1, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R1T2);
            Level.set(pos+2, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R1T3);
            Level.set(pos+3, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R1T4);
            Level.set(pos+4, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R1T5);
            Level.set(pos+49, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R2T1);
            Level.set(pos+50, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R2T2);
            Level.set(pos+51, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R2T3);
            Level.set(pos+52, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R2T4);
            Level.set(pos+53, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R2T5);
            Level.set(pos+54, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R2T6);
            Level.set(pos+55, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R2T7);
            Level.set(pos+99, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R3T1);
            Level.set(pos+100, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R3T2);
            Level.set(pos+101, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R3T3);
            Level.set(pos+102, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R3T4);
            Level.set(pos+103, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R3T5);
            Level.set(pos+104, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R3T6);
            Level.set(pos+105, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R3T7);
            Level.set(pos+148, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R4T1);
            Level.set(pos+149, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R4T2);
            Level.set(pos+150, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R4T3);
            Level.set(pos+151, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R4T4);
            Level.set(pos+152, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R4T5);
            Level.set(pos+153, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R4T6);
            Level.set(pos+154, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R4T7);
            Level.set(pos+155, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R4T8);
            Level.set(pos+156, Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R4T9);
            GameScene.updateMap( pos );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+1 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+2 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+3 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+4 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+49 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+50 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+51 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+52 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+53 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+54 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+55 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+99 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+100 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+101 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+102 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+103 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+104 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+105 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+149 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+150 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+151 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+152 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+153 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+154 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+155 );
            Dungeon.observe();
            break;

}

public static void leave( int pos ) {
    switch(Dungeon.level.map[pos]) {
        case Terrain.MT_EARTH_SHADOW_R1T1:
            Level.set(pos, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R1T1);
            Level.set(pos+1, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R1T2);
            Level.set(pos+2, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R1T3);
            Level.set(pos+3, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R1T4);
            Level.set(pos+4, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R1T5);
            Level.set(pos+49, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R2T1);
            Level.set(pos+50, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R2T2);
            Level.set(pos+51, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R2T3);
            Level.set(pos+52, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R2T4);
            Level.set(pos+53, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R2T5);
            Level.set(pos+54, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R2T6);
            Level.set(pos+55, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R2T7);
            Level.set(pos+99, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R3T1);
            Level.set(pos+100, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R3T2);
            Level.set(pos+101, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R3T3);
            Level.set(pos+102, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R3T4);
            Level.set(pos+103, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R3T5);
            Level.set(pos+104, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R3T6);
            Level.set(pos+105, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R3T7);
            Level.set(pos+148, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R4T1);
            Level.set(pos+149, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R4T2);
            Level.set(pos+150, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R4T3);
            Level.set(pos+151, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R4T4);
            Level.set(pos+152, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R4T5);
            Level.set(pos+153, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R4T6);
            Level.set(pos+154, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R4T7);
            Level.set(pos+155, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R4T8);
            Level.set(pos+156, Terrain.MT_EARTH_R4T9);
            GameScene.updateMap( pos);
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+1 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+2 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+3 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+4 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+49 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+50 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+51 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+52 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+53 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+54 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+55 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+99 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+100 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+101 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+102 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+103 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+104 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+105 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+149 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+150 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+151 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+152 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+153 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+154 );
            GameScene.updateMap( pos+155 );
            Dungeon.observe();
            break;
```

}
}

I want to make this work in such a way that when the player moves, all the positions that are occupied by MT_EARTH terrain are turned into MT_EARTH_SHADOW terrain.

I could just copy and paste all these lines and change the position modifiers for each position (for each tile of all four rows), but that seems tedious and unnecessary.

How can I shorten this up and make it work for all the required tiles?

Comment: You're mixing data with code, something that you don't want to do. Get the map data out of the code and into some persisting data such as a database, or text file or XML file -- whichever will work best for you, and then write code to read the data and translate it into your model.

Comment: Duplicate codes should become methods. Only a change of parameter could be enough then.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yet he is asking how to toggle the state of the terrain. Two ideas: use a static variable attached with some class. Alternately, pass a pointer to some instance of an object representing terrain--maybe a singleton, though those aren't favored often anymore. (global state) In other words, represent the terrain in a way that lets you use a single switch.

Comment: @synchronizer: He'll want to M-V-C this application for sure, change the model and the view should react automatically because it's been wired to do so.

Comment: Hmm, mixing data with code, eh? Even on the conceptual level, this is really helpful. I guess I really am just having problems because I'm not using good design principles. That said, learning that design principle of separating data from code will save me a lot of time in the future. It's not an easy fix, but I really appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing the approach and instead of assigning each tile a terran type have the collections representing terrain types and move these types between these collections.

Comment: Would you elaborate on a way to implement what you describe (on a high level)?

Comment: I actually don't know if elaboration is important for this answer to be helpful. I think he means that I can have one chunk of code somewhere called [COLLECTION] that references all the relevant tiles once. Then, I can keep referring back to [COLLECTION] when I want to affect all tiles of that type.  I'd be changing all the tiles of type, regardless of position, for this to work in a fairly concise manner.